# Trying to hover on a menu and click on a link in the sub-menu but no luck

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning to hover over a menu and click on a link int he sub-menu.

The scenario is go to the URL "https://www.amazon.in", hover over "Hello Sign in" and then click on the link "Start here".

I can hover over "Hello Sign in" using moveToElement() and sub menu is opening, but couldn't click on the link "Start here".

Here is my code.

```
WebElement signUp = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(signUp).build().perform();

WebElement startHere = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Start here")));
startHere.click();
```

Comment: Learned three things from the three answers below. 1.My ignorance of spelling. 2. usage of Explicit wait. 3. chained search to locate elements. Thanks.

Comment: Three answers solved my problem. I couldn't decide which one to upvote.

Comment: you can do the upvote for multiple answers,If it is really helped your problem

Comment: Yeah, upvoted but it won't be reflectled as my reputation is not enough to do upvote.

Comment: You need minimum 15 Reputation to do the upvote. However, you can do the upvote, once you have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The link text includes a dot at the end, you missed it in your code, Try `By.linkText("Start here.")` or `By.partialLinkText("Start here")`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below modified code and it's working as expected. First you can find the new Customer Div and then directly access the start here link as below.

```
WebElement signUp = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(signUp).build().perform();

WebElement newCustomer=driver.findElement(By.id("nav-flyout-ya-newCust"));
newCustomer.findElement(By.xpath(".//a")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. chained search. Superb!!

Answer (score 1):

To access the URL `https://www.amazon.in` then hover over **Hello Sign in** and then click on the link **Start here.** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element with text as *Hello Sign in* to be visible, then *Mouse Hover* over it and then induce *WebDriverWait* for the element with text as **Start here.** *to be clickable* and you can use the following solution :

- Code Block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
  WebElement signUp = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount")));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(signUp).build().perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Start here."))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot :

[image: amazon_in]

Comment: Thank you. you've just posted a short tutorial for a simple wait.